# Impliment nice editor for dynamically generated text areas with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

I have a form in which there are multiple text areas And i want those areas are editable with Nice editor.
For hardcoded text areas in the form is working with this code.

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

But if i generate dynamic text areas there nice editor is not working I am using this code to generate dynamic text areas.

```
function add() {

//Create an input type dynamically.
var element = document.createElement("input");

//Create Labels
var label = document.createElement("Label");
label.innerHTML = "New Label";     

//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute("type", "textarea");
element.setAttribute("value", "");
element.setAttribute("name", "Test Name");
element.setAttribute("style", "width:200px");

label.setAttribute("style", "font-weight:normal");

// 'foobar' is the div id, where new fields are to be added
var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

//Append the element in page (in span).
foo.appendChild(label);
foo.appendChild(element);
}
```

And the html

```
<button id="button" value="Add" onClick:"javascript:add();">
```

Comment: You should complete your question before posting it...

Comment: Oh, it gone hidden Now i made it in code snippet it is visible now.

Comment: On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4evgtwzp/) I get `ReferenceError: add is not defined`... (I assumed your `onClick:""` was a typo)

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer Check this code pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPMPNq

Comment: *clicked the "set" button 60 times* OK. Enough with the random. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416728

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer Its ok i am not using any jquery i am a vanila js guy That is a jquery solution i am looking for somthing in JS only is it possible to do anything like that?

Comment: Actually, JQuery only simplifies the DOM elemnt selection and a couple methods. In plain JS you can do what JQuery does. (But I'm not that good in JS-JQuery transforms)

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer Any way thank you for your solution if you can add that to this question properly i can accept that as answer. Best,