# Unable to remove an element from dynamic jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, wysiwyg, nicedit

I am creating a dynamic form with a wysiwig editor nice editor which goes like this.

Scripts needed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

Html

```
        <div id="p_scents">
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="title">
                <textarea name="description[]" rows="20" cols="80"></textarea>
            </p>
        </div>
```

And the jquery function

```
$(function () {
     var editors = {}; //Keep track of all added nicEditors for removal later
     var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');


     $(document).on('click', '#addScnt', function () {
var elm = $('<div class="con"><input type="text" id="Text1" value="" /></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
         var elm = $('<textarea NAME="description[]"></textarea>').appendTo(scntDiv); // Add the textarea to DOM

         var curSize = $('textarea[name="description[]"]').length; //Get the current SIZE of textArea

         editors[curSize] = new nicEditor().panelInstance(elm[0]); //Set the Object with the index as key and reference for removel

         elm.after($('<a/>', { //Create anchor Tag with rel attribute as that of the index of corresponding editor
             rel: curSize,
                 'class': "remScnt",
             text: "Remove",
             href: '#'
         })).next().andSelf().wrapAll($('<p/>')); //add it to DOM and wrap this and the textarea in p

     });

     $(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var elem = $(this).prev('textarea'); //Get the textarea of the respective anchor
         var index = this.rel; //get the key from rel attribute of the anchor
         editors[index].removeInstance(elem[0]); //Use it to get the instace and remove
         delete editors[index]; //delete the property from object
         $(this).closest('con').remove();
         $(this).closest('p').remove(); //remove the element.

     });
 });
```

This script is taken from this stack overflow question.
[NicEdit html editor for managing dynamic add/remove textareas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416728/nicedit-html-editor-for-managing-dynamic-add-remove-textareas)

With this scrip i want to attach a text field as title the above script is creating the same but once it is created if i press on remove button it is not getting removed only the text area is getting removed where am i going wrong how can i fix this?

Updated fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/eEUEW/34/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.parent()` and `.prev()`

replace

```
$(this).closest('con').remove();
$(this).closest('p').remove();
```

with

```
$(this).parent().prev().remove();
$(this).closest('p').remove();
```

Comment: Thank you you saved the day, also can you explain me a little bit about parent.prev.remove();

Comment: doing `parent()` will select the top of element or from element `a.remScnt` to `p` and `prev()` will go to previous `p` element which is `div.con`